# How to add the following files to a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a PDF file and a Video File. How do them to my webpage as a download link so people can download it?

Also, if somebody can kindly suggest me a basic jQuery lightbox to display images clicked in a gallery.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a web-page I assume you have some form of hosting for that web-page? And you have some way of uploading files to that hosting platform - e.g. FTP.

So you might have have an FTP account which already contains a document called "index.html" which you can access at:

http://www.example.com/index.html

So you should just be able to upload your PDF and video files to the same FTP account, and they would then be available to download at:

http://www.example.com/mydocument.pdf

http://www.example.com/myvideo.wmv

You can then edit your index.html and add the following lines of HTML (inside the `<body>` somewhere):

```
<a href="mydocument.pdf">Download PDF</a>
<a href="myvideo.wmv">Download video</a>
```

As for jQuery photo lightboxes, the suggestions given by the others would all be perfectly good.

I'm a little confused as to, if you are hoping to add in JavaScript modules to your web-page, how is it that you don't already know how to serve simple static files and link to them from HTML? So sorry if I misunderstood your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="path_to_the_file.mov"> download the file</a>
```

and for a lightbox I like this

http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Comment: nice example :) the site says "While Thickbox had its day, **it is not maintained any longer**, so we recommend you use some alternatives."

Comment: it is still the best one in my opinion

Comment: @samconne: please tell that to the developers of that plugin. they obviously think otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

Lightbox was originally [done in Mootools](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). Two of the current well known jQuery clones of LightBox are

1. [jQuery LightBox Plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)
2. [prettyPhoto - jQuery LightBox](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#!prettyPhoto)